# What does "$file =~ /^\./" mean in perl?

Tags: perl, conditional-statements

I'm just getting started in Perl, and I've been given a script that I don't fully understand. Specifically, I don't understand this condition line:

```
if ( -d "$dirPath\\$file" and not $file =~ /^\./ )
```

The first part of the condition is whether the file exists in the directory, but I don't understand the "not $file =~ /^./ ", what does it mean ?
I did some research through the internet but wasn't able to find anything.

Comment: check if a variable content starts with a dot. If it contains a file name, it checks if it is a hidden file.

Comment: `-d ` check if the file IS a directory http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html

Comment: Didn't you google "equals sign tilde slash caret backslash dot slash?" ;) Many of Perl's operators and built-in variables are hard to google because they contain special characters, so it helps to know where to look in the official documentation. Operators are documented in [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop); (`=~` is [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Binding-Operators), the match operator, which follows `=~`, is [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#m%2f_PATTERN_%2fmsixpodualngc)). *continued*

Comment: `^\.` is a regular expression, documented in [perlretut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html) and [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html). If you have the perldoc utility installed on your system, you can view these by entering e.g. `perldoc perlretut` on the command line.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot I've added your comments to the accepted answer, for future reference (I know not everyone bothers to read comments).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `not $file =~ /^\./` part of that statement tests the string in the scalar `$file` against the regex `^\.`

The regex checks for `^` begining of string, followed by `.`

Dots (periods) have to be escaped with a backquote `\` because in regex dots have a special meaning (it means any single character).

So it will check if the string inside `$file` starts with a dot. This operation will return 1 if it matches or 0 if it doesn't and the `not` negates it. The upshot can been read as "if the file does not start with a dot".

You can also use the `!~` operator (does not match regex operator) to achieve the same result:

```
if ( -d "$dirPath\\$file" and $file !~ /^\./ )
```

To link some of [ThisSuitIsNotBlack](https://stackoverflow.com/users/176646/thissuitisblacknot) comments here in an answer, the matches operator `=~` is documented inside perl documentation page perlop, which can be viewed with `perldoc perlop` and can be found online at the [Perl website](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html). The relevant section is [Binding Operators](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Binding-Operators). Perl Regex has a couple of perl documentation pages [perlretut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html) (`perldoc perlretut`) and [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) (`perldoc perlre`).

Answer (score 3):

`=~`  is Perl's regular expression operator

it is matching `$file` to the regular expression   `^\.`

briefly this means

- `^`   - match to the beginning of the string
- `\.`  - search for a literal . character

Thus: Since this expression is also negated with a `not` operator if the filename does not begin with a . character then this expression will return true.

More information [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Binding-Operators)